# Bluemix services with ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET web application on IBM Bluemix and connect it with some Watson services.

For now, from catalogue I can only get the ASP.NET 5 Cloudant Starter Application. From some youtube videos I saw, there was a sample with ASP.NET and Watson Q&A service, but cannot find it anymore.

Does someone can help to get .Net working with IBM Bluemix Watson services? I would like TTS and Visual Recognition, but help on any service connection can be usefull to understand what-s missing on my solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Watson Q&A service was [replaced](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/blog/2015/11/11/watson-question-and-answer-service-to-be-withdrawn/) by some other services.  There is now a sample using the Visual Recognition service available [on github](https://github.com/degrim/asp.netcore-watson-visual-recognition).  This sample provides a `VisualRecognitionService` class which shows how to call the Watson REST API using `HttpClient`.

The `Startup` function in Startup.cs shows how to handle parsing the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable as a JSON object and storing those values in the application's configuration where the `VisualRecognitionService`'s constructor can access them to use when calling the REST API.

The `VrClient` function in `VisualRecognitionService` creates and returns an `HttpClient` with the needed request headers for contacting the Watson REST API including the `X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out` header which is used to opt out of sharing data with Watson services.

```
private HttpClient VrClient()
{
    var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
        UseCookies = true,
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
    };

    var auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_vrCreds.Username + ":" + _vrCreds.Password));

    HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(httpHandler, new LoggingHandler());
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_vrCreds.Url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", auth);

    if (learningOptOut)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out", learningOptOut.ToString());
    }

    return client;
}
```

The simplest example of using the `VrClient` is in the `GetClassifiersAsync` method in `VisualRecognitionService` which retrieves a list of available image classifiers (default classifiers + any user-created classifiers):

```
public async Task<ClassifiersResponse> GetClassifiersAsync()
{
    ClassifiersResponse model = null;
    using (var client = VrClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/v2/classifiers?version=" + VersionReleaseDate);

            var msg = string.Format("{0} {1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ClassifiersResponse>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

The `ClassifiersResponse` model uses a `JsonProperty` attribute for mapping the JSON response back to the .Net property.

```
public class ClassifiersResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("classifiers")]
    public Classifier[] Classifiers { get; set; }

    public ClassifiersResponse()
    {
        Classifiers = new Classifier[0];
    }
}
```

Other Watson services can be accessed using similar methods to call their REST APIs.

Hopefully this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: The is an error "Failed to retrieve results from Watson service" but it can be solved, changing a single line on WatsonVRService.cs, method ClassifyAsync. Where it is:

WatsonVRViewModel viewModel = null;

Should be changed to:

WatsonVRViewModel viewModel = new WatsonVRViewModel();

And that's it! It works!! Thanks!! ;)

Comment: Good catch, I had planned to refactor that to return some form of status in the model.  Right now if it fails to connect to the Watson services it returns null, which is when that error message was meant to be displayed.  Adding a null check to the mapper will fix this error and still display the error when the `HttpClient` fails to connect to Watson.  In `WatsonVRImagesMapper.Map` just check if `toModel` is null first and create a new model if it is.  This won't affect when the service fails to connect because the mapper is only called on success.